# Conditionally handling denied access behavior in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-authorization

I'm trying to create an ASP.Net Core app which contains both MVC and API controllers in single project. For authenticating I use IdentityServer4.

Currently when the user is not authorized for a request he is always redirected to `Account/AccessDenied` path regardless of authentication scheme. But I want to keep this behavior only for MVC controllers. For API requests I just want to return 403 status code.

Configuration:

```
services
    .AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(ApiResourceProvider.GetAllResources())
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddInMemoryClients(clientStore.AllClients);

services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = tokenAuth.Issuer,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = tokenAuth.Audience,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = tokenAuth.SecurityKey,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
        };
    });
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using cookies you can override the AccessDeniedPath like the following

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            }).AddCookie("Cookies", (options) =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Authorization/AccessDenied";
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was quite simple but not obvious: it's needed to explicitly specify authentication scheme in `[Authorize]` attribute.

I tried to specify `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` on a controller level but it seems that setting `[Authorize(Roles = RoleHelper.MobileWorker)]` on the action level overrides the auth schema. 
So I created a custom attribute which is derived from `Authorize` but with properly set auth scheme.